# Reading JSON from webpage throws error at first but works after

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-store-apps

I have an app that gets a JSON string from a webpage and parses it, etc. The problem I'm having is that the first run of the app throws me this error:

```
A first chance exception of type
'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll An
error occurred while sending the request. System.Net.WebException:
Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond 128.0.46.69:80
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
exception)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
ar)
```

After that, if I start it from the start menu it works great.
I dont know why the first time it wont work but after it starts working.

Any ideas? Thanks anticipated

Here's some code:

```
private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
        {
            if (this._groups.Count != 0) return;
            int loopNo = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                loopNo++;
                try
                {
                    // Fetchibg JSON file from http
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://etc/data.php"));

                    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
                    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
                        SampleDataGroup group = new SampleDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                                    groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                                    groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                                    groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString());

                        foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
                        {
                            JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                            group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                               itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                               itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                               itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                               itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
                        }
                        this.Groups.Add(group);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exp.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }
```

I used the splitpage template. I also posted this question on MSDN but the only answer I got was from a moderator stating that there's a problem with my network or the webvpage I try to access.

There isn't any problem with my network nor the webpage. **It's really odd that it never works the first time but always the second.**

Comment: Did you add private networks access (`privateNetworkClientServer`) on the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have added that. Same problem, after which I removed it...same problem again

Comment: Why are you concerned about first-chance exceptions? Ignore them.

Comment: I do not wish to do that since it can cause problems on the first startup of the app after it's released to the public.